# Accessing WSO2 ESB, GREG and AS from external machine

Tags: macos, wso2, port, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

I worked over the last weeks with wso2 products using some of the tutorials which were posted on the wso2 site.

Unfortunately I only found tutorials, where all the products run on the same machine.

What do I have to do, if I want to run the products on different machines. I want a configuration where:
- ESB runs on machine 1
- AS and GREG run onmachine 2
- Proxy-services in the ESB or a web servcie in AS are invoked from machine 3

I run these examples on some macs, I think the main problem are the ports which are used. Can somebody help me with the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate your configurarion problem?

With this configuration you have to be sure that from one server you can ping the another servers and that in each server you have the ports 9443 and 9763 (by default) open to the network. this is the only requirement you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is nothing new. In a typical production deployment each of the servers run in their own physical/virtual machines.

when you are calling a service, you calling an endpoint uniquely identified by IP address:port/contextPath

If the setup is in the same local machine the IP address would be 'localhost'.

First you have to learn the tcp/ip basics, the question is not related to wso2 servers IMHO.